# Exception when using ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow() in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

My WebApi client project is loosing the *WindowsIdentity* of the current user when executing *SendAsync* Method from *HttpClient*.

*HttpContext.User* returns the application pool identity. Not the impersonated *WindowsIdentity*.

The client project is .NET Standard, so it can be used in .NET Framework and .NET Core.

When using RestSharp all works without problems and *ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()* is not needed. (I can´t use RestSharp because the clients are generated by NSwag.)

**.NET Framework:**

When using *ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()* the Identity will be correctly delegating to the server.

**.NET Core:**

When using .NET 7 following exception will be thrown:

> Cannot call Set on a null context

Exception:

```
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedInternal(SafeAccessTokenHandle token, Action action)
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
at System.Net.Http.CurrentUserIdentityProvider.GetIdentity()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPoolManager.GetConnectionKey(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri proxyUri, Boolean isProxyConnect)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPoolManager.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri proxyUri, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, Boolean isProxyConnect, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPoolManager.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpAuthenticatedConnectionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandlerStage.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext()
```

Minimal code snippet:

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = new()
{
    Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
    Host = "localhost",
    Port = 7042
};

var urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
urlBuilder.Append(uriBuilder.ToString() + "/WeatherForecast");

HttpClientHandler handler = new()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    PreAuthenticate = true
};
         
HttpClient client = new(handler);
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = new HttpMethod("GET");
var url = urlBuilder.ToString();
request.RequestUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Does the ExcecutionContext need to be used differently in .NET Core?

Comment: You're using a completely different runtime built to run on Linux and MacOS, not just Windows. Besides, your existing Web API code wouldn't impersonate the caller either without *explicit* configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core differ quite vastly (and .NET Framework and .NET (Core) too). Current implementation uses `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedInternal` which has the following:

```
ExecutionContext? currentContext = ExecutionContext.Capture();

// Run everything else inside of ExecutionContext.Run, so that any EC changes will be undone
// on the way out.
ExecutionContext.Run(currentContext, ...)
```

And `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();` will set current context to null, which results in the [`InvalidOperation_NullContext`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/dff23ec24c412191ce9fa7b40f289097f74b7ceb/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ExecutionContext.cs#L443) (i.e. the [`Cannot call Set on a null context`](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/2783c3862982ab31f2704933210dff9f3c37a6b1/src/runtime/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/Resources/Strings.resx#L2681) message).

It seems that you will need to dabble with [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation), i.e. something like (not tested, maybe multitargeting will be required):

```
#if NETFRAMEWORK
    ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();
#endif
```

Read also:

- [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core: Impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation):

  > ASP.NET Core doesn't implement impersonation. Apps run with the app's identity for all requests, using app pool or process identity.  If the app should perform an action on behalf of a user, use `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated` or `RunImpersonatedAsync` in a terminal inline middleware in `Program.cs`. Run a single action in this context and then close the context.
- [Support multiple .NET Framework versions in your project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file)
- [ASP.NET Core SynchronizationContext: There Isn’t One](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) - one of the biggest changes in ASP.NET Core - removal of the synchronization context, not sure but maybe this is related.

Comment: Thanks. Conditional compilation seems to be working.